About the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{4\pi^2 |\xi|^2}$ in $n$-dimensions

Note that $\frac{1}{4\pi^2 |\xi|^2}$ is a spherically symmetric homogeneous distribution of degree $-2$, so its inverse Fourier transform is a spherically symmetric homogeneous distribution of degree $-n + 2$.

The sentence above is in my textbook. But I cannot verify it. Because when I tried to find the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|\xi|^2}$, I got $$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi \cdots \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i |\xi||x| \cos\theta}}{|\xi|^2} |\xi|^{n-1} \sin^{n-2}\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi \, \cdots \, d\xi$$
whose degree cannot be $2-n$. Is there anything wrong? Or the degree of it equals to other number in fact?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty...\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ik_1\xi_1+...+ik_n\xi_n}}{\xi_1^2+...+\xi_n^2}d\xi_1...d\xi_n=\int_0^\infty dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty...\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik_1\xi_1+...+ik_n\xi_n-t(\xi_1^2+...+\xi_n^2)}d\xi_1...d\xi_n$$
$$=\pi^{\frac n2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{k_1^2+...+k_n^2}{4t}}}{t^{\frac n2}}dt\overset{x=\frac1t}{=}\pi^{\frac n2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{k_1^2+...+k_n^2}4x}x^{\frac n2-2}dx=\pi^{\frac n2}\Big(\frac 4{k_1^2+...+k_n^2}\Big)^{\frac n2-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\frac n2-2}dt$$
